# Error while i try to read a content of a text file - 'cannot convert string to char'

Tags: c#

I have to read a text file (it contains 5 records), but get an error that I cannot convert `string` to `char` at Environment.NewLine. I have to read a particular line. I want to use for loop instead of foreach.

Would you please give me a hint how to solve this error?

```
   using System;
   using System.IO;

   public class Example
   {
       public static void Main()
       {
          string fileName = @"C:\some\path\file.txt";

          string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
          string[] lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine);

          foreach (string line in lines) {
          Console.WriteLine(line);
       }
    }
```

Comment: change this `text.Split(Environment.NewLine);` to this `text.Split('\n');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) in this case:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);

foreach (string line in lines) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: string path = @"C:\some\path\file.txt"
            string[] lines;
            lines = new string[447];  // Now this time I am taking 447 records//
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
               
            }
            Console.WriteLine(lines[13]);

            Console.ReadLine();  // I tried this way its working but I changed my records to 447 and want to read the text after 13th record in the text file and try to read till end of .txt file?//

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload for `Split()` which takes a `string` as an argument.

However there is one that takes an array of `string` with a second argument of `StringSplitOptions`.

Try this:

```
string[] lines = text.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Thank you.I tried my code its working but this time i changed my records to 447 and want to read from 13 record to till end of text file?